# Regular expression to match numeric digit does not work without ^$

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that matches number between 1 and 28:

```
[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]
```

This does not work without modifying it to:

```
^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])$
```

Can anybody explain why do I need this? And I want to use this in between of a string.

Comment: You are missing parentheses, hence the text matched by your regex does not show up in groups. Try using `([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])`.

Comment: Isn't that obvious once you read a documentation about regex patterns? Or didn't you read any?

Comment: I tried using ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]), this does not work,perhaps ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])$ works..

Comment: But what does it mean that it does not work? Isn't it matching anything (which I strongly doubt) or isn't it matching the text you want (which is quite possible, see the answers below)?

Comment: it is matching only numbers between 1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `^` and `$` do is make the regex match only from start to end.

Without those, `122` will match as well (`1` and `22`).

---

What you can do, if you want to use it to find substrings is to add the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matcher instead:

```
\b([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\b
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/dG1hI5/2)

---

Another alternative, if your number can be part of a word is to use [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!<\d)([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(?!\d)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/mP6hF3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is constructed to check the entire number. Adding anchors `^` and `$` ensures that the string matches your expression in its entirety, as opposed to matching some part of the string.

For example, string `12345` would match without anchors, because `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `12`, and `23` are all substrings of `12345` that represent numbers between `1` and `28`.

With anchors, however, it wouldn't match, making your second expression correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use anchors to allow matching of the whole string of selected numbers. The ^ will anchor on the start of the string, the $ will anchor on the end of the string.